# Robotium: How to update prefs before Activity is started?

Tags: android, testing, sharedpreferences, robotium, instrumentation

I have several test methods in my class. For one of my tests I need to update application preferences before test is started, i.e. before the `Activity` under a test is started. I'm using Robotium lib for testing, so my test class is extended from `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need a context, this is fairly easy to get as long as you have instrumentation available. This means you cannot do it in your test class constructor but can in the setup method.

```
Context context = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
```

The above will give you a context of the application under test. With this reference you can do anything to shared preferences you would be able to do normally within your application, e.g.:

```
final SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
```

Then perform any edits you want and then commit it as so:

```
preferencesEditor.commit();
```

Comment: This works if you have only one test, but I have several and I need prefs to be updated for only one. And I need to update it before this test is started, i.e. before the Activity under a test is started.

Comment: Then either place the code into the one test you need it or create a new test class before your activity is launched. If your activity is already launched then finish it and relaunch it. I typically find it best to start every test from scratch anyway because test shared state is fairly bad practice.

Comment: But the Activity is already running when test method is invoked, isn't it? So what I need is to update prefs and probably restart it?

Comment: It is only invoked if you said getActivity() before the test was run, for instance in the setup method. Place this setup code before it and you will be fine.